# How to loop cUrl without leaking memory?

Tags: php, memory, curl, libcurl, memory-leaks

I am looping this code (and more):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, utf8_encode($body));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

When I do the, the memory heaps up with every loop. This is because $ch is getting bigger and bigger.

For the script I'm working on, it is not possible to close the cUrl connection every while, so somehow I have to clear $ch partly.

Is that possible? Clear the part that was build here without clearing other set_opt's I set before in the script (password for connection, etc.)?

I really hope someone can help me, I would really much appreciate the help.

SK

Comment: How are you measuring that "$ch is getting bigger and bigger"?

Comment: Also, I'm not understanding why it is not possible to close the curl connection on every loop. If your app is performance sensitive, you've already lost by using curl (or any other external resource on the internet).